# Can't install driver with printui. Is this because the driver certificate expired?

Tags: c++, printing, driver

I want to install a virtual printer driver with printui, but I get "**Operation could not be completed (error 0x00000002)**"(Os is Win7 x64). Is this because the certificate used to sign the driver has expired? Or it has some other causes? If yes, then how can I get more information about the error (I'm not a C programmer)?

Here is the code to install the driver:

```
int APIENTRY _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     LPTSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     int       nCmdShow)
{
    if (wcsstr(lpCmdLine, L"/chkxps"))
    {
        if (!PrinterExists(L"Microsoft XPS Document Writer"))
        {
            DispError(L"A MediSmart ePrinter nem telepíthető, mivel nem található XPS nyomtató a rendszerben");
            return -10;
        }
        return 0;
    }


    LPWSTR printername = L"MediSmart ePrinter";
    LPWSTR printername1 = L"MediSmart ePrinter - HealthFund";
    LPWSTR printername2 = L"MediSmart ePrinter - B2B Electronic";
    LPWSTR printername3 = L"MediSmart ePrinter - B2B Paper based";
    LPWSTR portname = L"NUL:";

    bool inst = wcsstr(lpCmdLine, L"/uninst") == NULL;

    if (inst)
    {
        PRINTER_DEFAULTS pdef;
        pdef.pDatatype = NULL;
        pdef.pDevMode = NULL;
        pdef.DesiredAccess = SERVER_ACCESS_ADMINISTER;

        DWORD oneed;
        DWORD err;

        HANDLE hxcv;
        if (!OpenPrinter(L",XcvMonitor Local Port", &hxcv, &pdef))
        {
            DispError(L"A virtuális nyomtató port létrehozása nem sikerült");
            return -1;
        }
        XcvData(hxcv, L"AddPort", (LPBYTE)portname, (wcslen(portname) + 1)*2, NULL, NULL, &oneed, &err);
        ClosePrinter(hxcv);
        if (err && err != ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS)
        {
            DispError(L"A virtuális nyomtató port létrehozása nem sikerült");
            return -2;
        }
    }

    //TODO ez nem lesz igy jo, ha majd drivert akarunk frissiteni
    if (!inst || !PrinterExists(printername))
    {
        typedef void (CALLBACK *RunDllEntry)(HWND hwnd, HINSTANCE hinst, LPWSTR lpszCmdLine, int nCmdShow);

        HMODULE hmod = LoadLibrary(L"printui.dll");
        if (!hmod)
        {
            DispError(L"A virtuális nyomtatót nem sikerült telepíteni: a printui.dll nem található");
            return -3;
        }
        RunDllEntry entry = (RunDllEntry)GetProcAddress(hmod, "PrintUIEntryW");
        if (!entry)
        {
            FreeLibrary(hmod);
            DispError(L"A virtuális nyomtatót nem sikerült telepíteni: hibás printui.dll");
            return -3;
        }
        WCHAR cmd[1000];
        if (inst)
        {
            wsprintf(cmd, L"/if /m \"%s\" /r \"%s\" /f \"%s\\mseprinter.inf\"", printername, portname, lpCmdLine);
            entry(NULL, hmod, cmd, SW_SHOW);
            wsprintf(cmd, L"/if /m \"%s\" /r \"%s\" /f \"%s\\mseprinter_hf.inf\"", printername1, portname, lpCmdLine);
            entry(NULL, hmod, cmd, SW_SHOW);
            wsprintf(cmd, L"/if /m \"%s\" /r \"%s\" /f \"%s\\mseprinter_b2bel.inf\"", printername2, portname, lpCmdLine);
            entry(NULL, hmod, cmd, SW_SHOW);
            wsprintf(cmd, L"/if /m \"%s\" /r \"%s\" /f \"%s\\mseprinter_b2bpb.inf\"", printername3, portname, lpCmdLine);
            entry(NULL, hmod, cmd, SW_SHOW);
        }
        else
        {
            wsprintf(cmd, L"/dl /n \"%s\"", printername);
            entry(NULL, hmod, cmd, SW_SHOW);
            wsprintf(cmd, L"/dl /n \"%s\"", printername1);
            entry(NULL, hmod, cmd, SW_SHOW);
            wsprintf(cmd, L"/dl /n \"%s\"", printername2);
            entry(NULL, hmod, cmd, SW_SHOW);
            wsprintf(cmd, L"/dl /n \"%s\"", printername3);
            entry(NULL, hmod, cmd, SW_SHOW);
        }
        FreeLibrary(hmod);
    }

    #ifndef _DEBUG
    if (inst)
        RemoveDirectoryTree(lpCmdLine);
    #endif

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Win32 error code 0x00000002 = ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND: "The system cannot find the file specified.". But you don't specify neither the function that returns you the error code.

Comment: @Gonmator: Oh, thanks. When I googled for "Operation could not be completed (error 0x00000002)" I only got printer related errors

Comment: You can look at a list of system error codes [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I'm guessing the error is at `XcvData()`? Make sure `portname` is correct and try removing the `+ 1` from `(wcslen(portname) + 1)*2`.

Comment: @jliv902: Thanks. Sorry, forgot to specify at what line the error is. Is at the 4 calls of: entry(NULL, hmod, cmd, SW_SHOW);

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer: I have to run it with a command argument that specifies the path...

Comment: just complementing, running printui to install a driver that dont have a valid or outdate certificate will prompt a window asking for confirmation about confidence about the driver provider.